# Change float content order depending on its position selected by LaTeX's float mechanism

Tags: floats

I'm (still) going to develop a class that will use wide margins and put some contents into it. In contrast to `tufte-book`, which sets the positioning parameters for floats as `htbp` by default, I would like to allow true floats. Furthermore, I'd like to offer an environemtn which a) floats and b) puts its caption (in the margin) either above or below the figure, depending on the positioning selected by the float mechanism. While I can handle this if a position is provided (the optional argument of `figure` or `table`), I'd like to do the same if no optional argument was specified. Since the content and hence the height of the figure is the same for both cases, it would not change the positioning of the figure.

I'm quite sure that I have read about this some years ago, but I don't find a hint via google. For the MWE, I omit the positioning in the margin but simply want to output the caption below or above the figure's content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=7cm,left=1.5cm,right=1cm,includemp]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\myt{t}\def\myp{p}\def\myb{b}
\newcommand*\widefigure[3][]{%
  % #1: Position
  % #2: Figure
  % #3: Caption
  \def\@tempa{#1}%
  \begin{figure}[#1]%
    \rlap{%
      \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\columnsep+\marginparwidth}%
        \ifx\@tempa\myb
          \caption{#3}#2%
        \else\ifx\@tempa\myt
          #2\caption{#3}
        \else\ifx\@tempa\myp
          \caption{#3}#2%
        \else
         % What if no position is specified?
        \fi\fi\fi
      \end{minipage}}
  \end{figure}%
}
\begin{document}
\widefigure[b]{\rule{\textwidth}{5cm}}{foo}
\lipsum[1-4]
\widefigure[t]{\rule{\textwidth}{5cm}}{foo}
\lipsum[2]
\widefigure{\rule{\textwidth}{5cm}}{foo}
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "true floats". Also even if the float uses `[t]` it may not be set in top position if flushed with `\clearpage` (which basically forces all floats to be `[p]`)

Comment: By "true floats" I mean that (at best) everything that is provided by LaTeX's floating mechanisms should be recognized. Hence, if LaTeX decides to put a float with a positioning specifier `b` on an entire page, the order of caption and figure should adapt to it. I know that the MWE given above is far from perfect since I don't know how to find out what type of positioning LaTeX's float mechanism is testing.

Comment: Thanks David for pointing to this Question and the answer!